# problem saving openGL FBO larger than window

Tags: opengl, fbo, openframeworks

I'm rendering into an OpenGL offscreen framebuffer object and like to save it as an image. Note that the **FBO** is larger than the display size. I can render into the offscreen buffer and use it as texture, which works. I can "scroll" this larger texture through the display using an offset, which makes me confident, that I render into a larger context than the window.

If I save the offscreen buffer to an image file it always gets cropped. The code fragment for saving is:

```
void ofFBOTexture::saveImage(string fileName) { 
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT); 
    // get the raw buffer from ofImage
    unsigned char* pixels = imageSaver.getPixels();
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 1024, 1024, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels); 

    imageSaver.saveImage(fileName); 
}
```

Please note, that the image content is cropped, the visible part is saved correctly (which means no error in pixel formats, GL_RGB issues etc.), but the remaining space is filled with one color.

So, my question is - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue.

I have to activate the fbo for saving its contents:

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);
// save code
...
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

while only selecting the fbo for `glReadPixels` via

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);
```

doesn't suffice.

(All other things where correct and tested, eg. viewport sizes, width and height of buffer, image texture etc.)

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you. Could you expand on how you obtain the fbo variable? I can't find what to include to access glGenFrameBuffers, which is what I think is used.

Comment: 2. GLuint fbo;
   glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo); // 1==numbers of fbo to create
   glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);

Comment: I'm developing for Windows, but I found an excellent description on the OS X dev site here: http://tinyurl.com/7cbs7sr

Answer (score 0):

Two questions to start: How are you creating imageSaver and are you sure your width and height are correct (e.g. are you trying to save a 1024 x 1024 image?  What size are you getting)?

Comment: 1. The imageSaver is an openframeworks image object. To avoid any possible errors I even created it through loading an empty bitmap file with size and depth of my desired target image. 
2. I get an 1024x1024 image, as desired but only content equal to the rendered window. everything else is "empty"

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, this has been quite common behaviour with OpenGL graphics drivers for a long time - I recall running up against exactly the same issue on nVidia Geforce 3 cards at least a decade ago, and I adopted a similar solution - rendering to an offscreen texture.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you have the wrong viewport size or something similar.