# How to take screenshot in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, save, screenshot, glreadpixels

How to take a screenshot of an OpenGL window in C++ and save it to file.

I found the [`glReadPixels()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) function,
but I don't know what to do next. Where I can set path to a file, for example?

If not difficult, write code, please.

Answer (score 30):

This piece of code captures the OpenGL window and export to a BMP file. You must have [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) library to run it.

```
// Make the BYTE array, factor of 3 because it's RBG.
BYTE* pixels = new BYTE[3 * width * height];

glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

// Convert to FreeImage format & save to file
FIBITMAP* image = FreeImage_ConvertFromRawBits(pixels, width, height, 3 * width, 24, 0x0000FF, 0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, false);
FreeImage_Save(FIF_BMP, image, "C:/test.bmp", 0);

// Free resources
FreeImage_Unload(image);
delete [] pixels;
```

Comment: Would be sensible to use ```GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE``` for the array too, instead of the windows-specific ```BYTE```.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```GLubyte```.

Comment: @Mortennobel Would be better if you used `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`, since `glReadPixels` is packing and not unpacking :)

Answer (score 13):

*[glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)* will copy the bits into a memory buffer that you supply. You have to manually format the data (to the image format of your choice) and write it to disk after *[glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml)* returns.

Comment: With what function may write memory buffer to disk?

Comment: @EthanHunt: `fwrite` writes data to a FILE*, `fopen` gives you a FILE* corresponding to a filename you specify. But don't ignore the part about the image format, that's the tricky bit.

Answer (score 8):

**Runnable example**

[image]

Each time you click with the mouse on the window, a `tmpX.ppm` file is created with the current screenshot.

You can view this file for example with `eog` on Linux, and inspect it with a text editor.

To render without showing a window, see: [How to use GLUT/OpenGL to render to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

static GLubyte *pixels = NULL;
static const GLenum FORMAT = GL_RGBA;
static const GLuint FORMAT_NBYTES = 4;
static const unsigned int HEIGHT = 500;
static const unsigned int WIDTH = 500;
static unsigned int nscreenshots = 0;
static unsigned int time;

/* Model. */
static double angle = 0;
static double angle_speed = 45;

static void init(void)  {
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    pixels = malloc(FORMAT_NBYTES * WIDTH * HEIGHT);
    time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
}

static void deinit(void)  {
    free(pixels);
}

static void create_ppm(char *prefix, int frame_id, unsigned int width, unsigned int height,
        unsigned int color_max, unsigned int pixel_nbytes, GLubyte *pixels) {
    size_t i, j, k, cur;
    enum Constants { max_filename = 256 };
    char filename[max_filename];
    snprintf(filename, max_filename, "%s%d.ppm", prefix, frame_id);
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(f, "P3\n%d %d\n%d\n", width, HEIGHT, 255);
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            cur = pixel_nbytes * ((height - i - 1) * width + j);
            fprintf(f, "%3d %3d %3d ", pixels[cur], pixels[cur + 1], pixels[cur + 2]);
        }
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}

static void draw_scene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

static void display(void) {
    draw_scene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
}

static void idle(void) {
    int new_time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    angle += angle_speed * (new_time - time) / 1000.0;
    angle = fmod(angle, 360.0);
    time = new_time;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        puts("screenshot");
        create_ppm("tmp", nscreenshots, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 255, FORMAT_NBYTES, pixels);
        nscreenshots++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GLint glut_display;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    atexit(deinit);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc main.c -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10, OpenGL 4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.63.

**Vulkan**

This example just worked: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd/examples/screenshot/screenshot.cpp how to run it: [Is it possible to do offscreen rendering without Surface in Vulkan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885309/is-it-possible-to-do-offscreen-rendering-without-surface-in-vulkan/64651042#64651042)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simple and quick solution.

- Outputs a TARGA file but **can easily be converted to PNG** (script provided).
- No extra libraries required.
- Will work with both C and C++ (with some minor changes).
- **Note:** The output file should have the `tga` file extension.

Here is the code:

```
void saveScreenshotToFile(std::string filename, int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {    
    const int numberOfPixels = windowWidth * windowHeight * 3;
    unsigned char pixels[numberOfPixels];

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight, GL_BGR_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    FILE *outputFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    short header[] = {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, (short) windowWidth, (short) windowHeight, 24};

    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header), 1, outputFile);
    fwrite(pixels, numberOfPixels, 1, outputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    printf("Finish writing to file.\n");
}
```

And calling the function:

```
saveScreenshotToFile("test.tga", 1200, 900);
```

A bash script to convert TARGA files to PNG:

```
for oldFileName in *.tga; do
    [ -f "$oldFileName" ] || break         # Break out if no .tga files found.
    newFileName=${oldFileName//.tga/.png}
    convert $oldFileName $newFileName
    rm $oldFileName
    echo "Converted $oldFileName to $newFileName"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Saving that data to a file is something you'll either have to do yourself or use a third-party library for - OpenGL has no such feature.

Windows .bmp is probably the easiest if you're looking to do it yourself - Wikipedia has a [pretty good explanation of the file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Otherwise you can use image saving/loading libraries: libpng, libjpeg, etc. for low-level control, or [devIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/) (there are others, but this is my favorite, and it's an extremely versatile library that goes well with GL) for high-level "just do it" image i/o.

Answer (score 1):

You can save screenshot with @Rafael's answer and OpenCV:

```
void Game::saveScreenshotToFile(std::string filename, int windowWidth, int windowHeight) {    

    cv::Mat img(windowHeight, windowWidth, CV_8UC3);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, (img.step & 3) ? 1 : 4);

    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, img.step/img.elemSize());
    glReadPixels(0, 0, img.cols, img.rows, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
    cv::flip(img, img, 0);
    //cv::imshow("Image",img);
    //cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::imwrite(filename, img);
    }
```

Thanks for OpenCV: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098883/10152334

Answer (score 0):

Generally, OpenGL don't provide functions to save image. I think the fastest and simplest way to do this is save to .[PPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) format. However, this kind of format is uncompressed which means it's file size would be very large. And it can be support only by quite a few programs nowadays.

I prefer to save image to .png file which is compressed but also gives lossless image and supported by many browsers. To save the OpenGL to .png format, I first recommend the [PNGwriter](http://pngwriter.sourceforge.net/). It's pretty simple and easy to use. For example, to save a pixel of a image with color (R, G, B) in the position (x, y), your code will be(see "quickstart" in the PNGwriter website):

```
pngwriter PNG(width, height, 1.0, fileName); // "1.0" stand for the white background
PNG.plot(x, y, R, G, B);
PNG.close();
```

Note that, since the PNGwriter save each pixel starting from the top-left corner of the image, while the array get from glReadPixels() start from the bottom-left of the window, your code to save the whole image might probably look like this:

```
GLfloat* pixels = new GLfloat[nPixels];
glReadPixels(0.0, 0.0, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
pngwriter PNG(width, height, 1.0, fileName);
size_t x = 1;   
size_t y = 1;
double R, G, B;
for(size_t i=0; i<npixels; i++) // "i" is the index for array "pixels"
{
      switch(i%3)
     {
           case 2:
                 B = static_cast<double>(pixels[i]); break;
           case 1:
                 G = static_cast<double>(pixels[i]); break;
           case 0:
                 R = static_cast<double>(pixels[i]);
                 PNG.plot(x, y, R, G, B);     // set pixel to position (x, y)
                 if( x == width )             // Move to the next row of image
                 {
                       x=1;
                       y++;
                  }
                  else                       // To the next pixel
                  { x++; }
                  break;
     }
}
PNG.close();
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file/14324292#14324292 for a PPM  | PNG | FFMPEG one.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Ciro Santilli OurBigBook.com 's answer to include threading and better performance.

```
#include <thread>
#include <Windows.h>
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL\GL.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static GLubyte *pixels = NULL;
static const GLenum FORMAT = GL_RGBA;
static const GLuint FORMAT_NBYTES = 4;
static const unsigned int HEIGHT = 500;
static const unsigned int WIDTH = 500;
static unsigned int nscreenshots = 0;
static unsigned int gameTime;
static bool grabScreen = false;
static bool threadRunning = false;


/* Model. */
static double angle = 0;
static double angle_speed = 45;

static void init(void)  {
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    pixels = (GLubyte*)malloc(FORMAT_NBYTES * WIDTH * HEIGHT);
    gameTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
}

static void deinit(void)  {
    free(pixels);
}

static void create_ppm(char *prefix, int frame_id, unsigned int width, unsigned int height,
    unsigned int color_max, unsigned int pixel_nbytes, GLubyte *pixels) {
    size_t i, j, k, cur;
    enum Constants { max_filename = 256 };
    char filename[max_filename];
    sprintf(filename, "%s%d.ppm", prefix, frame_id);
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "w");
    fprintf(f, "P3\n%d %d\n%d\n", width, HEIGHT, 255);
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            cur = pixel_nbytes * ((height - i - 1) * width + j);
            fprintf(f, "%3d %3d %3d ", pixels[cur], pixels[cur + 1], pixels[cur + 2]);
        }
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }
    fclose(f);
}

static void draw_scene() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}

static void savepixels()
{
    threadRunning = true;
    create_ppm("tmp", nscreenshots, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 255, FORMAT_NBYTES, pixels);
    nscreenshots++;
    threadRunning = false;
}

static void display(void) {
    draw_scene();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    if (grabScreen){
        grabScreen = false;
        if (threadRunning){
            printf("Thread running\n");
        }
        else{
            glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
            puts("screenshot");
            std::thread t{ savepixels };
            t.detach();
        }
    }
}

static void idle(void) {
    int new_gameTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    angle += angle_speed * (new_gameTime - gameTime) / 1000.0;
    angle = fmod(angle, 360.0);
    gameTime = new_gameTime;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (state == GLUT_DOWN && grabScreen == false) {
        grabScreen = true;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GLint glut_display;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    atexit(deinit);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```