# glReadPixels always returns the same value in glClearColor

Tags: c++, opengl

I've been struggling to understand the output of glReadPixels, which appears to be straightforward in theory, but actually produces puzzling (at least to me) results.

Let's assume I have a simple fragment shader that draws a single triangle with a color value of vec4(0.2, 0, 0, 0), whereas the background color is set to (0.3, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0), like so:

[image]

Below is the complete code (with the exception of shader construction) that I use to produce the image above:

```
#include "shader.h" // shader compile/link/use 
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

const int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 16; 
const int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 16; 

//============= shader code ==========================

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 440
in vec2 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
})glsl";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 440
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{   
    outColor = vec4(0.2,0.,0.,0.);
})glsl";

//============= c++ entry point ==========================

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, "test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum res = glewInit();

    // triangle data (xy-position)
    float vertices[] = {
    0.0f, 0.5f, 
    0.5f, -0.5f, 
    -0.5f, -0.5f  
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // enable vertex xy-position attribute 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // compile, link and use shader program
    Shader shader(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);
    shader.Use();

    // rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

       glClearColor(0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
       glFlush();

       // read pixels from backbuffer 
       GLubyte data[DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT];
       glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

       for (int i = 0; i < DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT; i++) {
           int a = data[i]; // implicit conversion of unsigned char to int
           std::cout << a << std::endl;
       }
       std::getchar(); // wait for user input

       glfwSwapBuffers(window);
       glfwPollEvents();
    }

   glfwTerminate(); 
   return 0;
}
```

Note, that I am using a default framebuffer, which will treat my color values as normalized signed integers and will convert them to the range between [0-255], i.e. my background color is going to be (76, 255, 255, 0), whereas my geometry color is going to be (51, 0, 0, 0).

And so after I draw my geometry and swap the buffers, I get my image. Now I want to read out the color values. In order to do it, I insert the necessary glReadPixels related code right before I swap buffers:

```
GLubyte* data = new GLubyte[DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT];
glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

In order to facilitate the process of examining pixel values that I read out from the framebuffer, I just extract red channel, hence the size of data necessary to accommodate pixel data is `DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT`. Furthermore, it means that the values I print out are supposed to be '76' for the background color, and '51' for geometry.

Surprisingly, every single red channel pixel data (all the DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT pixels are printed) I print out happens to be '76', as if geometry is ignored. Note that I read pixels after the draw call and before I swap buffers.

I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know what I am missing in here.

Comment: If you get color for the background but not for the object, it seems `glReadPixels` is reading between the "clear color" and the "swap buffers" calls. Or it's reading from the `front buffer` instead of the default `back buffer` after a first swap you're missing somehow.

Comment: What you're doing looks right. Are you _sure_ you're only seeing background pixels? From your picture, there's going to be a lot of background pixels before the first geometry one...

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841923/44729) as a base.

Comment: @Rabbid76: The `glFlush` is not necessary. `glReadPixels` introduces a synchronization point, which implicitly finishes all operations leading up to the call of `glReadPixels` in question, before doing the pixel readout. Most likely OP doesn't specify which buffer to read from and accidently reads from the wrong one.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes, I read between clear color and swap buffer, but right after I draw my geometry. So I assume that by the point I read my backbuffer, it already contains pixels generated by geometry.

Comment: @Bahbar I print out all the pixels I extracted from the backbuffer (or so I believe, you can examine the code to verify my claim).

Comment: @genpfault Thank you for the guidelines, I hope I edited it according to the aforementioned set of rules. Corrections and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Bahbar It turns out that you were right. There is a minimal size enforced by the window manager that overrides the values I provide during window creation. Consequently, I was examining only a portion of the framebuffer, which actually contains the pixels I sought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the full story. It is worth mentioning that as [Bahbar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148383/bahbar) said, I was reading out pixels correctly. However, I did have a  wrong assumption on the size of my default framebuffer, whose dimensions are set to the dimensions of a window that I create.

The window size that I specify in the code with `glfwCreateWindow` is 16x16. Clearly, the image that I attached in the original question has greater width.

The [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga0e2637a4161afb283f5300c7f94785c9) (see `glfwSetWindowSize`) states the following: *"The window manager may put limits on what sizes are allowed. GLFW cannot and should not override these limits"*. Well it turns out that I cannot set width less than 120 pixels on my Windows 10 machine. Subsequently, examining `data` array of 120x16 pixels, rather than 16x16 pixels, revealed that the value of '51' is indeed, properly recorded.

Then in order to make sure that the geometry is drawn exactly where I want it to be drawn, I need to call `gViewport` before my draw calls in order to specify desired transformation from normalized device coordinates (NDC) to pixels in my window (or to pixels in my renderbuffer or a texture, if I am rendering off-screen with a user-defined framebuffer object). Below is the output and a slightly modified code provided by [genpfault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46622608/6135458) (his code is completely self-contained and contains shader construction bits that my example lacks):

```
GLEW version: 2.0.0
GLFW version: 3.2.1 Win32 WGL EGL VisualC
GL_VERSION  : 4.5.0 NVIDIA 376.53
GL_VENDOR   : NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER : GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2

76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
```

The code itself contains a `glViewport` call (right before rendering loop) and a slightly modified printing loop in order to match the output to the actual image:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load(const char* shader, ...)
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, shader);
        while (shader)
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg(args, GLenum);
            AttachShader(prog, type, shader);
            shader = va_arg(args, const char*);
        }
        va_end(args);
        glLinkProgram(prog);
        CheckStatus(prog);
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus(GLuint obj)
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if (glIsShader(obj)) glGetShaderiv(obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
        if (glIsProgram(obj)) glGetProgramiv(obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
        if (status == GL_TRUE) return;
        GLchar log[1 << 15] = { 0 };
        if (glIsShader(obj)) glGetShaderInfoLog(obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log);
        if (glIsProgram(obj)) glGetProgramInfoLog(obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log);
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    static void AttachShader(GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src)
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &src, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        CheckStatus(shader);
        glAttachShader(program, shader);
        glDeleteShader(shader);
    }
};

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 130
    in vec2 position;
    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    })glsl";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 130
    out vec4 outColor;

    void main()
    {   
        outColor = vec4(0.2,0.,0.,0.);
    })glsl";


const int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 16;
const int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 16;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, "test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum res = glewInit();

    std::cout << "GLEW version: " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLFW version: " << glfwGetVersionString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VERSION  : " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VENDOR   : " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_RENDERER : " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl << std::endl;

    // triangle data (xy-position)
    float vertices[] =
    {
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // enable vertex xy-position attribute 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // compile, link and use shader program
    GLuint program = Program::Load
        (
        vertexShaderSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        fragmentShaderSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        NULL
        );
    glUseProgram(program);

    glViewport(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    // rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClearColor(0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glFlush();

        // read pixels from backbuffer 
        GLubyte data[DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT];
        glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

        for (int y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT-1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < DISPLAY_WIDTH; x++)
            {
                std::cout << (int)data[y*DISPLAY_HEIGHT + x] << " "; // implicit conversion of unsigned char to int
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::getchar();
        std::cout << std::endl;

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Lastly, I couldn't upload a picture using stackoverflow's functionality, so here is a link to imgur for those who are interested: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AogHw.jpg.

If anyone could let me know if this can be accepted as an answer I'll just go ahead and hit the button. Or perhaps someone else could give a more meaningful answer. Thank you for the input guys!

Answer (score 2):

Workin' fine on my Debian Stretch box:

```
GLEW version: 2.0.0
GLFW version: 3.2.1 X11 GLX EGL clock_gettime /dev/js Xf86vm shared
GL_VERSION  : 3.0 Mesa 13.0.6
GL_VENDOR   : Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER : Mesa DRI Intel(R) Kabylake GT2 

76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 51 51 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 
76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76 76
```

All together (dropped the shader `#version` to `130` because Mesa doesn't support anything past GL 3.0 in non-Core contexts):

```
// g++ main.cpp -lGLEW -lGL -lglfw
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 130
in vec2 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
})glsl";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = R"glsl(#version 130
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{   
    outColor = vec4(0.2,0.,0.,0.);
})glsl";


const int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 16; 
const int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 16; 


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, "test", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    GLenum res = glewInit();

    std::cout << "GLEW version: " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLFW version: " << glfwGetVersionString() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VERSION  : " << glGetString( GL_VERSION ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_VENDOR   : " << glGetString( GL_VENDOR ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GL_RENDERER : " << glGetString( GL_RENDERER ) << std::endl;

    // triangle data (xy-position)
    float vertices[] =
    {
        0.0f, 0.5f, 
        0.5f, -0.5f, 
        -0.5f, -0.5f  
    };

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // enable vertex xy-position attribute 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // compile, link and use shader program
    GLuint program = Program::Load
        (
        vertexShaderSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
        fragmentShaderSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
        NULL
        );
    glUseProgram( program );

    // rendering loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

    glClearColor(0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glFlush();

    // read pixels from backbuffer 
    GLubyte data[DISPLAY_WIDTH * DISPLAY_HEIGHT];
    glReadPixels(0, 0, DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < DISPLAY_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < DISPLAY_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            int a = data[i]; // implicit conversion of unsigned char to int
            std::cout << a << " ";;
            i++;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I finally found out what is happening. The window size that I specify with `glfwCreateWindow` is 16x16. Clearly, the image that I attached has greater width. The [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga371911f12c74c504dd8d47d832d095cb) (see glfwSetWindowSize) states the following: "The window manager may put limits on what sizes are allowed. GLFW cannot and should not override these limits". Well it turns out that I cannot  set width less than 120 pixels.

Having said that, examining `data` array revealed that the value of '51' is indeed, properly recorded.