# Converting data from glReadPixels() to OpenCV::Mat

Tags: c++, opengl, opencv, glreadpixels

I want to get every OpenGL frame from an animation with **glReadPixels()** and convert the data to **OpenCV::Mat**. I know that **glReadPixels()** gets the data by rows from the lower one to upper one, from left to right. On the other hand, OpenCV stores the data differently.

Does anybody know any library or any tutorial/example that helps me to convert data from **glReadPixels** to a **OpenCV:Mat** in C++?

**SUMMARY**

```
 OpenGL frame      ----------------------->        CV::Mat

Data from left to right,                    Data from left to right,
bottom to top.                              top to bottom.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First we create an empty (or unititialized) `cv::Mat` for our data to be read into directly. This can be done once at startup, but on the other hand `cv::Mat::create` doesn't really cost much when the image already has matching size and type. The type depends on your needs, usually it's something like `CV_8UC3` for a 24-bit color image.

```
cv::Mat img(height, width, CV_8UC3);
```

or

```
img.create(height, width, CV_8UC3);
```

Then you have to account for `cv::Mat` not neccessarily storing image rows contiguously. There might be a small padding value at the end of each row to make rows 4-byte aligned (or 8?). So you need to mess with the pixel storage modes:

```
//use fast 4-byte alignment (default anyway) if possible
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, (img.step & 3) ? 1 : 4);

//set length of one complete row in destination data (doesn't need to equal img.cols)
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, img.step/img.elemSize());
```

Next, the type of the matrix influences the format and type parameters of `glReadPixels`. If you want color images you have to keep in mind that OpenCV usually stores color values in BGR order, so you need to use `GL_BGR(A)` (which were added with OpenGL 1.2) instead of `GL_RGB(A)`. For one component images use either `GL_LUMINANCE` (which sums the individual color components) or `GL_RED`, `GL_GREEN`, ... (to get an individual component). So for our `CV_8UC3` image the final call to read it directly into the `cv::Mat` would be:

```
glReadPixels(0, 0, img.cols, img.rows, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
```

Finally, OpenCV stores images from top to bottom. So you may need to either flip them after getting them or render them flipped in OpenGL in the first place (this can be done by adjusting the projection matrix, but keep an eye on triangle orientation in this case). To flip a `cv::Mat` vertically, you can use [`cv::flip`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-flip):

```
cv::flip(img, flipped, 0);
```

So to keep in mind OpenCV:

- stores images from top to bottom, left to right
- stores color images in BGR order
- might not store image rows tightly packed

Comment: Really really nice answer. I was already working on the flipping but I didn't pay attention to glPixelStorei. Thanks

Comment: I cannot call GL_BGR, I don't know why the linker cannot find it because I have got the latest version

Comment: @Jav_Rock It was introduced with OpenGL 1.2. So if your hardware and driver support it (which is very likely, unless you bought your graphics card 20 years ago), you just need to define this symbol, by including a reasonably new [`glext.h`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h) or by using an extension managment library in the first place (like GLEW), which should bring its own header with constant definitions. This would be necessary once you want to use any functionality higher than 1.1, anyway (like PBOs, which might speed up you reading performance whe used properly).

Comment: Yeah, definetely glext.h fixes the problem. Now I got everything working with right colors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This comment is still being useful, if I could I would upvote it 20 times.

Comment: I tried this today and it returns a gray image. Any ideias? btw, GL_BGR is not defined, only GL_BGR_EXT (under windows, MSVC 2013)

Comment: @manatttta It should be defined if you have support for GL 1.2. And did you make sure the image format matches?

Comment: @ChristianRau I had to call wglMakeCurrent() as I am on Windows, MFC. Plus, I had to use GL_BGR_EXT instead of GL_BGR

Comment: If anyone wonders why this doesn't work is because cv::Mat::create only creates a header, you need to clone an existing Mat or initialize it with some values with cv::Mat::zeros for example.

Comment: @GáborFekete No, `create` *does* create storage for the matrix as well. It might not *initialize* that storage, but you don't care what's in it anyway, since you're you completely overwrite it in the next step anyway. But it's definitely allocated.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char* getPixelData( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 )
{
    int y_low, y_hi;
    int x_low, x_hi;

    if ( y1 < y2 )
    {
        y_low = y1;
        y_hi  = y2;
    }
    else
    {
        y_low = y2;
        y_hi  = y1;
    }

    if ( x1 < x2 )
    {
        x_low = x1;
        x_hi  = x2;
    }
    else
    {
        x_low = x2;
        x_hi  = x1;
    }

    while ( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        ;
    }

    glReadBuffer( GL_BACK_LEFT );

    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glPixelStorei( GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );

    unsigned char *data = new unsigned char[ ( x_hi - x_low + 1 ) * ( y_hi - y_low + 1 ) * 3 ];

    glReadPixels( x_low, y_low, x_hi-x_low+1, y_hi-y_low+1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );

    if ( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR )
    {
        delete[] data;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

use:

```
CvSize size = cvSize( 320, 240 );

unsigned char *pixel_buf = getPixelData( 0, 0, size.width - 1, size.height - 1 );

if ( pixel_buf == 0 )
    return 0;

IplImage *result = cvCreateImage( size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
memcpy( result->imageData, pixel_buf, size.width * size.height * 3 );
delete[] pixel_buf;
```