# loading opencv::mat images with alpha channel in opengl texture

Tags: opengl, opencv, alpha

I want to load the opencv::mat images with alpha channel to OpenGL texture.

With the help of following posts I could manage to load RGB images into an OpenGL texture from opencv::mat.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809833/opencv-image-loading-for-opengl-texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097756/converting-data-from-glreadpixels-to-opencvmat/9098883#9098883)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097756/converting-data-from-glreadpixels-to-opencvmat/9098883#9098883](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809833/opencv-image-loading-for-opengl-texture)

But when I try to load the image with an alpha channel, there is a problem.

Here is how the glTexImage2D function is called.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
                        0,                 // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 
                        GL_RGBA,            // Internal colour format to convert to
                        image.cols,          // Image width  
                        image.rows,          // Image height 
                        0,                 // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
                        GL_BGRA_INTEGER, // Input image format 
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // Image data type
                        image.ptr());        // The actual image data itself
```

Also, before rendering, I enable the blending by using glEnable(GL_BLEND);

If I specifyinput image format and internal color format to both be GL_RGBA / GL_BGRA, I get a segmentation fault, but if I set either of them or both of them to GL_RGBA_INTEGER, at least I can see the window, but just blank.

I can change the transparency and accordingly the window become more or less transparent, but there is no image in it. There is an image in the cv::mat as i can see it using cv::imshow, but somehow there seems a problem passing it to the OpenGL texture.

Could any one suggest something I might be missing. Thanks in advance.

P.S : I am new to OpenGL, I would really appreciate if explained with smallest detail.. :P

Comment: The `_INTEGER` pixel transfer formats do not make a lot of sense when used together with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, these are for special new packed integer formats like `UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1` (16-bits, where each component is a fractional portion of an integer type). Try using `UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` if you are going to use `GL_BGRA_INTEGER`, this at least makes sense.

Comment: Why are you using integer image formats to begin with? Traditional fixed-point / unsigned normalized is almost certainly what you want, you would be well aware why/when you needed an actual integer format.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. I was making mistake in the first step only, while reading the image in opencv. Once i corrected it, i could use GL_BGRA only. Thanks

Comment: can you post correct code? I am experiencing a similar problem..

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on my computer, able to load and display png texture.

The code in the question is adapted from the last answer in the following link.

[OpenCV image loading for OpenGL Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809833/opencv-image-loading-for-opengl-texture)

I post my working code (also adapted from the code in the aforementioned link) below

```
GLuint Texture;

cv::Mat image = cv::imread("textures/trashbin.png", -1);

cv::flip(image, image, 0);
glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// Set texture clamping method
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,     // Type of texture
    0,                 // Pyramid level (for mip-mapping) - 0 is the top level
    GL_RGBA,            // Internal colour format to convert to
    image.cols,          // Image width  i.e. 640 for Kinect in standard mode
    image.rows,          // Image height i.e. 480 for Kinect in standard mode
    0,                 // Border width in pixels (can either be 1 or 0)
    GL_BGRA, // Input image format (i.e. GL_RGB, GL_RGBA, GL_BGR etc.)
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // Image data type
    image.ptr());
```

Pay attention to 3 points:

- The -1 in the imread call at the second line. It tells OpenCV to load the alpha channel. I believe this is where the questioner had the problem.
- The GL_RGBA and GL_BGRA in the last function call.
- cv::flip(image, image, 0); was not necesssary for me, I actually had it commented out in my project. The reason might be I got the UV coordinates flipped in the first place.