# Opengl Blank Screen Trying to display opencv Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I'm trying to display OpenCV Mat image using Opengl, And I'm Getting blank screen. I'm new to OpenGL

Code:

```
img = imread("Test2.jpg", 1);
//img = Mat(640, 480, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
flip(img, img, 0);
```

Render Code:

```
glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB,img.cols , img.rows,0,GL_BGR,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);
glUniform1i(textureId, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

Interesting thing noted is that when I dynamically create Mat Image using

```
Mat(640, 480, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
```

The Mat image is being rendered correctly, But when I load image from local, I'm seeing blank screen. Is there anything I need to be taken care??

Thank you

Comment: does img.empty() return true?

Comment: No... I also checked with OpenCV imshow the img variable contains image.

Comment: Looks like you have not swapped the chain ie present the back buffer. Are those the only 3 OpenGL API calls you have made to render your image? You will have to invoke glFlush to flush the OpenGL buffers to the window. Besides you are using fixed function pipeline

Comment: @Asesh I have edited my render code

Comment: @Asesh Does this sufficient?? Or I need anything to be taken care???

Comment: This thread will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809833/opencv-image-loading-for-opengl-texture

Comment: @Asesh..  the link says about the byte arrangements... Actually i have checked that too

Comment: What about OpenGL frustum creation? Have you created one? Your code looks ok but you might have missed something else