# How to screencapture window that uses OpenGL?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I'm trying to capture the pixels of an OpenGL application (specifically, MEmu) and later convert it to an OpenCV Mat. I used the `hwnd2mat()` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148758/how-to-capture-the-desktop-in-opencv-ie-turn-a-bitmap-into-a-mat) as a reference but ran into some problems.

Only the window frame is captured, as seen here:

[image]

Further investigation led me to believe that the problem is that `StretchBlt` (or `BitBlt`) can't capture the OpenGL pixels.

I tried to use `glReadPixels` (and convert to Mat using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097756/converting-data-from-glreadpixels-to-opencvmat)), but it is not reading any pixels. The `wglCreateContext` returns `NULL`, probably because my application does not own the DC of MEmu. Therefore, `wglMakeCurrent` does nothing and the pixels are not read.

I was able to create a workaround modified version of `hwnd2mat` that gets the WindowRect of MEmu's hwnd but later uses `GetDC(NULL)` to capture only the portion of the screen where MEmu is located. This works but any windows that get on top of MEmu get captured aswell.

I can work with this, sure, but was wondering if there is a way to use glReadPixels on a window that I don't own or a way to ensure that hwnd2mat works on the contents of the window that is using OpenGL.

Comment: I think it isn't possible to get the pixels rendered with OpenGL from a window that you can't access its gl context. But in Windows 10 the "print screen" key does get all.