# OpenGL: Save framebuffer to image, file

Tags: c, visual-c++, opengl

I wrote some lines of code to draw a spinning rectangle:

```
#include "glut.h"
static GLfloat spin = 0.0; /* current angle */
void init(void) 
{
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel (GL_FLAT);
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(spin, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  /* rotate Oxyz (OZ) */
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); /* bgr-color: white; */
    glRectf(-25.0, -25.0, 25.0, 25.0); /* Rectangle */
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();  /* Swap 2 buffer */
}
void spinDisplay(void)
{
    spin = spin + 2.0;  /* Add 2 degrees for every loop action */
    if (spin > 360.0)
        spin = spin - 360.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();  /* Alert: Redraw */
}
/* Change window mode */
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); /* change viewport */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50.0, 50.0, -50.0, 50.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
/* Mouse interaction */
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
{
    switch (button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:  /* left mouse */
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(spinDisplay); /* idle mode switch to spinDisplay */
        break;
        //case GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON:  /* middle mouse button */
        //if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        //glutIdleFunc(NULL);
        //break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
/* main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);  /* double buffer */
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("spinning rectangle");
    init ();
    glutDisplayFunc(display); 
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape); /* reshape func (redraw) when window size changed */
    glutMouseFunc(mouse); /* mouse func */
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

And I wanna save framebuffer to image (JPEG, BMP, TIFF) or file. Could you tell me how? Do I need to use some lib like jpeglib, libtiff?

Comment: I'm curious: how are you using Visual Studio with Android?

Comment: Just an OpenGL example to get it work and then using NDK to make use of native code in Android app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take screenshot in opengl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844858/how-to-take-screenshot-in-opengl)

Comment: Not a duplicate. You might have multiple buffers to manipulate so I wouldn't compare it to a question about a simple screenshot.

Comment: I'd recommend putting your actual question above the code, so that people don't jump the jun and downvote what looks like a code-only question