# Is it possible to do offscreen rendering without Surface in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Similar to surfaceless context in OpenGL can we do it in Vulkan.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure it's even designed to do so from the start.

Instead of getting your images from a swapchain, create them and allocate and bind memory for it yourself.

Getting the result back will then require a copy into a host-visible readback buffer after the render.

Answer (score 3):

**SaschaWillems/Vulkan `renderheadless.cpp` example**

It seems that Vulkan is designed to support offscreen rendering better than OpenGL.

This is mentioned on this NVIDIA overview: https://developer.nvidia.com/transitioning-opengl-vulkan

This is a runnable example that I just managed to run locally: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd/examples/renderheadless/renderheadless.cpp

After installing the drivers and [ensuring that the GPU is working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card/692412#692412) I can do:

```
git clone https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan
cd Vulkan
git checkout b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd
python download_assets.py
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j`nproc`
cd bin
./renderheadless
```

and this immediately generates an image `headless.ppm` without opening any windows:

[image]

I have also managed to run this program an [Ubuntu Ctrl + Alt + F3 non-graphical TTY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66195/what-is-a-tty-and-how-do-i-access-a-tty), which further indicates it really does not need a screen.

Other examples that might be of interest:

- https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd/examples/screenshot/screenshot.cpp starts a GUI, and you can click a button to take a screenshot, and it gets saved to `screenshot
- https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd/examples/offscreen/offscreen.cpp render an image twice to create a reflection effect

Related: [How to use GLUT/OpenGL to render to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file/14324292#14324292)

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04, NVIDIA driver 435.21, NVIDIA Quadro M1200 GPU.