# OpenGL ES in SmartEyeGlass

Tags: opengl-es, sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I'm looking at the Sony SmartEyeGlass and it seems like the only way to interact with the "augmented reality layer" (what's drawn on the glasses) is through the proprietary Sony APIs.
I'm wondering whether there is a way to let OpenGL ES manage this layer as a GLSurfaceView ?
Or is there an alternative way to do 3D rendering on the glasses?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there isn't a special API to connect with OpenGL. The way how to achieve OpenGL rendering with SmartEyeglass is to render your content directly to a `Bitmap` and show it using `SmartEyeglassControlUtils.showBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)`

Here you will find a solution, how to render OpenGL to a `Bitmap`:
[Run Android OpenGL in Background as Rendering Resource for App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524212/run-android-opengl-in-background-as-rendering-resource-for-app)

Please let us know in comment, for what kind of application you need this OpenGL feature.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion.