# OpenGL, glBegin/glEnd is equivalent to one draw call?

Tags: opengl

When using glBegin/glEnd, is it equivalent to one draw call?

I mean, when using glDrawArrays, as I understand, that's the point when data is transferred to GPU (client side to server side). When using glBegin/glEnd, is data transferred to GPU only at the glEnd call? Or vertex are transferred one by one every glVertex/glNormal/glTexCoord call?

Comment: see nicols answer for exact details but its pretty safe to think of one glBegin/glEnd as one draw call

Comment: So, can I suppose that using glBegin/glEnd is similar in performance to using Vertex Arrays and glDrawArrays? Both are immediate mode.

Comment: @Ray No, you definitely can't. Vertex arrays are *not* immediate mode. The advantage of `glDrawArrays` over `glBegin/glEnd` does not just come from using GPU data right away (i.e. when using VBOs), but also from the fact that you don't make a driver call for each and every stupid little vertex. And that is a strength that plays out even for client side vertex arrays. So while in practice anything is possible and depends on your application and implementation the general rule is, that `glBegin/glEnd` is likely slower than `glDrawArrays` (no matter if using VBOs or not).

Comment: @Cristian Thanks for clarification. I just read in another answer that Vertex Arrays could be considered "immediate mode" because vertex data is stored in client side ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733934/what-does-immediate-mode-mean-in-opengl)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How these work is implementation dependent. At the very least, you can know that nothing gets transferred to the GPU until you call `glVertex`/`glVertexAttrib(0)`, since those are what provokes a vertex (ie: causes the attribute state to be sent). Whether vertex data are transferred immediately upon calling a provoking function, or if they are buffered and transferred at `glEnd` time, or perhaps even later than that, is entirely implementation dependent.

Also... you shouldn't care. If you're using immediate mode, it should be because you *don't care* about performance. If you cared, you'd be using buffer objects and modern rendering functionality, not immediate mode.

Comment: Could really be an inplementation that transfers every vertex at every glVertex call? I understand that every transfer to GPU incurs a performance cost that can be quite large.

Comment: @Ray: There could be. It's all up to how the implementation wants to implement it. And "transfers a vertex" doesn't necessarily mean "issues a rendering command". All it means is copying that vertex's data into some internal piece of memory, such that the GPU will eventually see and process that vertex.