# Why Does my OpenGL Program Run Slower with Display Lists?

Tags: c, opengl

In a desire to speed up a voxel renderer I have been writing, I precomputed the scene into a display list. The scene is a simple 50x50x3 blob of culled voxels, so that's 50*50*2+50*3*4 or 5600 quads. Each quad is associated with a texture so that's 22400 vertices each with a texture coordinate.

The speed difference is incredible: It takes well under 16ms for the non-list program to render a frame, and 50ms, wildly fluctuating, for the list program to render.

I read https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm and it suggested that performance doesn't improve if the program thrashes, as display lists use more memory. However, both versions of my program use a steady 10.0MB as far as I can tell from the system monitor.

I am currently using SDL2, freeglut3, an AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor × 4 and it's integrated graphics, Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880, and Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit, if this is some system specific issue.

How I am rendering without vertex lists is that this code is being called for every last voxel:

```
void draw_cube_culled(spritesheet * sheet, rect * front, rect * back, rect * left, rect * right, rect * top, rect * bot, float x, float y, float z, float s, renderstate * state) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sheet->sheet_image->texture);
    side_t side;
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //BOT--Y constant
        side = BOT;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(bot->left, bot->bot); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(bot->right, bot->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(bot->right, bot->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(bot->left, bot->top); glVertex3f(x, y, z+s);
        }
    //TOP--Y constant
        side = TOP;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(top->left, top->bot); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z);
            glTexCoord2f(top->right, top->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z);
            glTexCoord2f(top->right, top->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(top->left, top->top); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z+s);
        }
    //LEFT--X constant
        side = LEFT;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(left->left, left->bot); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(left->right, left->bot); glVertex3f(x, y, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(left->right, left->top); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(left->left, left->top); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z);
        }
    //RIGHT--X constant
        side = RIGHT;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(right->right, right->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(right->left, right->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(right->left, right->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(right->right, right->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z);
        }
    //back--Z constant
        side = BACK;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(back->right, back->bot); glVertex3f(x, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(back->left, back->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z);
            glTexCoord2f(back->left, back->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z);
            glTexCoord2f(back->right, back->top); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z);
        }
    //front--Z constant
        side = FRONT;
        if(state->side[side]) {
            glTexCoord2f(front->left, front->bot); glVertex3f(x, y, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(front->right, front->bot); glVertex3f(x+s, y, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(front->right, front->top); glVertex3f(x+s, y+s, z+s);
            glTexCoord2f(front->left, front->top); glVertex3f(x, y+s, z+s);
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

In order to generate the display lists I call this code once at initialization time (note that draw_diorama is the method I use to draw the scene in the normal code, so it calls the function above 50*50*3 times):

```
void diorama_compile(diorama * d) {
    glNewList(d->compiled,GL_COMPILE);
        draw_diorama(d);
    glEndList();
}
```

I am rendering the display list like so:

```
void draw_compiled_diorama(diorama * d) {
    glCallList(d->compiled);
}
```

This really confuses me because one code involves branching at least 6*50*50*3 times a screen, lots of reading different kinds of memory, floating point math all on the CPU and the other doesn't.

Comment: This not directly answers your question but just in case... You are using the 'old' (deprecated) way of OpenGL programming (fixed pipeline). It's worth to make an effort and learn the modern way, the programs are quite faster with shaders.

Comment: Display list was never good at performance (at least I never see any significant boost with them usually they made things worse even in the old days) Instead use **VBO** you do not need to go for shaders to use them and the performance boost is usually significant. See [VBO new vs. old OpenGL style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19629220/2521214) and here [simple complete GL+GLEW+GLSL+normal_shading in C++ example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre Yes upgrading to a VBO seriously increased the performance. It is a little annoying that I see display lists labeled as tools to increase performance when they do not, but oh well.

Comment: @unreproducable_butterfly they where meant to but the driver implementations where not done properly for them because VBO was a better choice at that time. For the same reason be careful with ATI/AMD gfx cards their OpenGL drivers are extremly sensitive to memory leaks in your App often leading to gfx errors especially in VBO rendering.