# In what way is WebGL2 immediate compared to retained mode OpenGL3?

Tags: opengl, webgl, opengl-3, webgl2

I have some previous experience with OpenGL3 from following the tutorials on learnopengl.com and have recently been learning how WebGL2 compares. I'm still a n00b, so excuse any misunderstandings.

One source of confusion I am having is that WebGL advertises itself as an "immediate-mode 3D rendering API", but I am having a hard time understanding what is actually different in the design pattern for writing a WebGL2 program vs an equivalent "retained" OpenGL3 program.

As I understand it, the basic flow of a retained mode OpenGL3 program is as follows;

- Create VBO's and VAO's through the appropriate API calls
- Bind a VAO
- Bind a VBO
- Fill the VBO with vertex attribute data
- Fill out the VAO with information on what attribute the bound VBO is describing and how to chop the buffer up.
- Repeat the above 3 steps as needed
- Bind a VAO
- Call glDrawArrays

In my understanding of the term "[retained mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode)", the reason why the above design pattern is considered retained is because all of the information on what to render is stored on the GPU and is not supplied by the client at render time. All the client has to do is tell the GPU which VAO to bind and instruct it to render. [Here is an example](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial2:_VAOs,_VBOs,_Vertex_and_Fragment_Shaders_(C_/_SDL)) from Khronos showing, as far as I can tell, the above design pattern. I have included the code below.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Ensure we are using opengl's core profile only */
#define GL3_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <GL3/gl3.h>

#include <SDL.h>

#define PROGRAM_NAME "Tutorial2"

/* A simple function that will read a file into an allocated char pointer buffer */
char* filetobuf(char *file)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    long length;
    char *buf;

    fptr = fopen(file, "rb"); /* Open file for reading */
    if (!fptr) /* Return NULL on failure */
        return NULL;
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END); /* Seek to the end of the file */
    length = ftell(fptr); /* Find out how many bytes into the file we are */
    buf = (char*)malloc(length+1); /* Allocate a buffer for the entire length of the file and a null terminator */
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET); /* Go back to the beginning of the file */
    fread(buf, length, 1, fptr); /* Read the contents of the file in to the buffer */
    fclose(fptr); /* Close the file */
    buf[length] = 0; /* Null terminator */

    return buf; /* Return the buffer */
}

/* A simple function that prints a message, the error code returned by SDL, and quits the application */
void sdldie(char *msg)
{
    printf("%s: %s\n", msg, SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}

void setupwindow(SDL_WindowID *window, SDL_GLContext *context)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) /* Initialize SDL's Video subsystem */
        sdldie("Unable to initialize SDL"); /* Or die on error */

    /* Request an opengl 3.2 context.
     * SDL doesn't have the ability to choose which profile at this time of writing,
     * but it should default to the core profile */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);

    /* Turn on double buffering with a 24bit Z buffer.
     * You may need to change this to 16 or 32 for your system */
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

    /* Create our window centered at 512x512 resolution */
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow(PROGRAM_NAME, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        512, 512, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!*window) /* Die if creation failed */
        sdldie("Unable to create window");

    /* Create our opengl context and attach it to our window */
    *context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(*window);

    /* This makes our buffer swap syncronized with the monitor's vertical refresh */
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);
}

void drawscene(SDL_WindowID window)
{
    int i; /* Simple iterator */
    GLuint vao, vbo[2]; /* Create handles for our Vertex Array Object and two Vertex Buffer Objects */
    int IsCompiled_VS, IsCompiled_FS;
    int IsLinked;
    int maxLength;
    char *vertexInfoLog;
    char *fragmentInfoLog;
    char *shaderProgramInfoLog;

    /* We're going to create a simple diamond made from lines */
    const GLfloat diamond[4][2] = {
    {  0.0,  1.0  }, /* Top point */
    {  1.0,  0.0  }, /* Right point */
    {  0.0, -1.0  }, /* Bottom point */
    { -1.0,  0.0  } }; /* Left point */

    const GLfloat colors[4][3] = {
    {  1.0,  0.0,  0.0  }, /* Red */
    {  0.0,  1.0,  0.0  }, /* Green */
    {  0.0,  0.0,  1.0  }, /* Blue */
    {  1.0,  1.0,  1.0  } }; /* White */

    /* These pointers will receive the contents of our shader source code files */
    GLchar *vertexsource, *fragmentsource;

    /* These are handles used to reference the shaders */
    GLuint vertexshader, fragmentshader;

    /* This is a handle to the shader program */
    GLuint shaderprogram;

    /* Allocate and assign a Vertex Array Object to our handle */
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    /* Bind our Vertex Array Object as the current used object */
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    /* Allocate and assign two Vertex Buffer Objects to our handle */
    glGenBuffers(2, vbo);

    /* Bind our first VBO as being the active buffer and storing vertex attributes (coordinates) */
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);

    /* Copy the vertex data from diamond to our buffer */
    /* 8 * sizeof(GLfloat) is the size of the diamond array, since it contains 8 GLfloat values */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), diamond, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Specify that our coordinate data is going into attribute index 0, and contains two floats per vertex */
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    /* Enable attribute index 0 as being used */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    /* Bind our second VBO as being the active buffer and storing vertex attributes (colors) */
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);

    /* Copy the color data from colors to our buffer */
    /* 12 * sizeof(GLfloat) is the size of the colors array, since it contains 12 GLfloat values */
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 12 * sizeof(GLfloat), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /* Specify that our color data is going into attribute index 1, and contains three floats per vertex */
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    /* Enable attribute index 1 as being used */
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    /* Read our shaders into the appropriate buffers */
    vertexsource = filetobuf("tutorial2.vert");
    fragmentsource = filetobuf("tutorial2.frag");

    /* Create an empty vertex shader handle */
    vertexshader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    /* Send the vertex shader source code to GL */
    /* Note that the source code is NULL character terminated. */
    /* GL will automatically detect that therefore the length info can be 0 in this case (the last parameter) */
    glShaderSource(vertexshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertexsource, 0);

    /* Compile the vertex shader */
    glCompileShader(vertexshader);

    glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &IsCompiled_VS);
    if(IsCompiled_VS == FALSE)
    {
       glGetShaderiv(vertexshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

       /* The maxLength includes the NULL character */
       vertexInfoLog = (char *)malloc(maxLength);

       glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexshader, maxLength, &maxLength, vertexInfoLog);

       /* Handle the error in an appropriate way such as displaying a message or writing to a log file. */
       /* In this simple program, we'll just leave */
       free(vertexInfoLog);
       return;
    }

    /* Create an empty fragment shader handle */
    fragmentshader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    /* Send the fragment shader source code to GL */
    /* Note that the source code is NULL character terminated. */
    /* GL will automatically detect that therefore the length info can be 0 in this case (the last parameter) */
    glShaderSource(fragmentshader, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragmentsource, 0);

    /* Compile the fragment shader */
    glCompileShader(fragmentshader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &IsCompiled_FS);
    if(IsCompiled_FS == FALSE)
    {
       glGetShaderiv(fragmentshader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

       /* The maxLength includes the NULL character */
       fragmentInfoLog = (char *)malloc(maxLength);

       glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentshader, maxLength, &maxLength, fragmentInfoLog);

       /* Handle the error in an appropriate way such as displaying a message or writing to a log file. */
       /* In this simple program, we'll just leave */
       free(fragmentInfoLog);
       return;
    }

    /* If we reached this point it means the vertex and fragment shaders compiled and are syntax error free. */
    /* We must link them together to make a GL shader program */
    /* GL shader programs are monolithic. It is a single piece made of 1 vertex shader and 1 fragment shader. */
    /* Assign our program handle a "name" */
    shaderprogram = glCreateProgram();

    /* Attach our shaders to our program */
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(shaderprogram, fragmentshader);

    /* Bind attribute index 0 (coordinates) to in_Position and attribute index 1 (color) to in_Color */
    /* Attribute locations must be setup before calling glLinkProgram. */
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderprogram, 0, "in_Position");
    glBindAttribLocation(shaderprogram, 1, "in_Color");

    /* Link our program */
    /* At this stage, the vertex and fragment programs are inspected, optimized and a binary code is generated for the shader. */
    /* The binary code is uploaded to the GPU, if there is no error. */
    glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);

    /* Again, we must check and make sure that it linked. If it fails, it would mean either there is a mismatch between the vertex */
    /* and fragment shaders. It might be that you have surpassed your GPU's abilities. Perhaps too many ALU operations or */
    /* too many texel fetch instructions or too many interpolators or dynamic loops. */

    glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL_LINK_STATUS, (int *)&IsLinked);
    if(IsLinked == FALSE)
    {
       /* Noticed that glGetProgramiv is used to get the length for a shader program, not glGetShaderiv. */
       glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

       /* The maxLength includes the NULL character */
       shaderProgramInfoLog = (char *)malloc(maxLength);

       /* Notice that glGetProgramInfoLog, not glGetShaderInfoLog. */
       glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderprogram, maxLength, &maxLength, shaderProgramInfoLog);

       /* Handle the error in an appropriate way such as displaying a message or writing to a log file. */
       /* In this simple program, we'll just leave */
       free(shaderProgramInfoLog);
       return;
    }

    /* Load the shader into the rendering pipeline */
    glUseProgram(shaderprogram);

    /* Loop our display increasing the number of shown vertexes each time.
     * Start with 2 vertexes (a line) and increase to 3 (a triangle) and 4 (a diamond) */
    for (i=2; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        /* Make our background black */
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* Invoke glDrawArrays telling that our data is a line loop and we want to draw 2-4 vertexes */
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, i);

        /* Swap our buffers to make our changes visible */
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        /* Sleep for 2 seconds */
        SDL_Delay(2000);
    }

    /* Cleanup all the things we bound and allocated */
    glUseProgram(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDetachShader(shaderprogram, vertexshader);
    glDetachShader(shaderprogram, fragmentshader);
    glDeleteProgram(shaderprogram);
    glDeleteShader(vertexshader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentshader);
    glDeleteBuffers(2, vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    free(vertexsource);
    free(fragmentsource);
}

void destroywindow(SDL_WindowID window, SDL_GLContext context)
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

/* Our program's entry point */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_WindowID mainwindow; /* Our window handle */
    SDL_GLContext maincontext; /* Our opengl context handle */

    /* Create our window, opengl context, etc... */
    setupwindow(&mainwindow, &maincontext);

    /* Call our function that performs opengl operations */
    drawscene(mainwindow);

    /* Delete our opengl context, destroy our window, and shutdown SDL */
    destroywindow(mainwindow, maincontext);

    return 0;
}
```

From reading through the design pattern for WebGL2 this seems to be exactly what we do with this specification too! More specifically, I have been looking at this example from [WebGL2 Fundementals](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.htm), which I have reproduced below.

```js
"use strict";

var vs = `#version 300 es

in vec2 a_position;
in vec4 a_color;

uniform mat3 u_matrix;

out vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  // Multiply the position by the matrix.
  gl_Position = vec4((u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1)).xy, 0, 1);

  // Copy the color from the attribute to the varying.
  v_color = a_color;
}
`;

var fs = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;

in vec4 v_color;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = v_color;
}
`;

function main() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }

  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  var colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_color");

  // lookup uniforms
  var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_matrix");

  // Create set of attributes
  var vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  // Create a buffer for the positons.
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

  // Set Geometry.
  setGeometry(gl);

  // tell the position attribute how to pull data out of the current ARRAY_BUFFER
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  var size = 2;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  // Create a buffer for the colors.
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  // Set the colors.
  setColors(gl);

  // tell the color attribute how to pull data out of the current ARRAY_BUFFER
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
  var size = 4;
  var type = gl.FLOAT;
  var normalize = false;
  var stride = 0;
  var offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

  var translation = [200, 150];
  var angleInRadians = 0;
  var scale = [1, 1];

  drawScene();

  // Setup a ui.
  webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#x",      {value: translation[0], slide: updatePosition(0), max: gl.canvas.width });
  webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#y",      {value: translation[1], slide: updatePosition(1), max: gl.canvas.height});
  webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#angle",  {slide: updateAngle, max: 360});
  webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#scaleX", {value: scale[0], slide: updateScale(0), min: -5, max: 5, step: 0.01, precision: 2});
  webglLessonsUI.setupSlider("#scaleY", {value: scale[1], slide: updateScale(1), min: -5, max: 5, step: 0.01, precision: 2});

  function updatePosition(index) {
    return function(event, ui) {
      translation[index] = ui.value;
      drawScene();
    };
  }

  function updateAngle(event, ui) {
    var angleInDegrees = 360 - ui.value;
    angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
    drawScene();
  }

  function updateScale(index) {
    return function(event, ui) {
      scale[index] = ui.value;
      drawScene();
    };
  }

  // Draw the scene.
  function drawScene() {
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // Clear the canvas
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);

    // Bind the attribute/buffer set we want.
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    // Compute the matrices
    var matrix = m3.projection(gl.canvas.clientWidth, gl.canvas.clientHeight);
    matrix = m3.translate(matrix, translation[0], translation[1]);
    matrix = m3.rotate(matrix, angleInRadians);
    matrix = m3.scale(matrix, scale[0], scale[1]);

    // Set the matrix.
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

    // Draw the geometry.
    var offset = 0;
    var count = 6;
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, offset, count);
  }
}


// Fill the buffer with the values that define a rectangle.
function setGeometry(gl) {
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array([
          -150, -100,
           150, -100,
          -150,  100,
           150, -100,
          -150,  100,
           150,  100,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Fill the buffer with colors for the 2 triangles
// that make the rectangle.
function setColors(gl) {
  // Pick 2 random colors.
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array([
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
          Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1,
      ]),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
}

main();
```

So with this in mind, why is WebGL2 considered immediate whereas modern, core OpenGL3 is considered retained? It appears that there is virtually a one-to-one correspondence in the API calls between the two. Does it have to do with how the VBO/VAO data is being stored (i.e. the browser stores these objects and sends them to the GPU every frame) or does have to do with the fact that we have to call drawArrays whenever we want to re-render our display (which is what we would have to do with core OpenGL3 too)?

I have read [this anwser here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961458/how-is-webgl-immediate-mode), but I was hoping for a more precise explanation comparing core OpenGL3 vs WebGL2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The naming is terrible, but immediate in "OpenGL immediate mode" is not the same term as in "immediate mode rendering API".

In OpenGL, immediate mode is usually used for the old glBegin/glEnd way of drawing, whereas immediate mode API means that you issue rendering commands yourself compared to specifying just the content as you usually do with HTML.

- OpenGL is always a immediate mode rendering API since you issue draw commands yourself.
- There is no retained mode OpenGL rendering API
- OpenGL1/2 (compatibility mode) is immediate mode OpenGL and an immediate mode rendering API.
- Both, OpenGL3(Core Profile) and WebGL2 are OpenGL retained mode, and both are immediate mode rendering APIs.
- SVG is considered a retained mode rendering APIs, since you only specify the content, but don't care how/when the content is rendered.