# Gnuplot 3d depthorder with multiple plots

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

Using this [gnuplotting entry](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-cubes/comment-page-1/#comment-529404) as inspiration, I am attempting to create a 3d histogram plot like shown:
[image: respects depthorder]
However, under high-angled views, the `depthorder` is not respected:
[image: does not respect depthorder]

The gnuplot (**version 5.2**) commands used to generate the plots include:

```
set terminal pngcairo  enhanced  size 800,600 
set output "cube_depthorder.png"
set cbrange [0:10] 
set palette defined ( 1 '#ff4c4d', 2 '#ce4c7d', 3 '#ae559e', 4 '#df866d', 5 '#ffb66d', 6 '#ffe7cf', 7 '#cecece', 8 '#6d6d6d', 9 '#4c4c8e', 10 '#4c4cef' )
set view 60,45,1,1
set xrange [-0.09:1.99] 
set xyplane at 0
set yrange [-0.1125:2.0125] 
set pm3d at s depthorder border
unset colorbox
splot   "-" binary record=(5,4) format="%double%double%double"   using 1:2:3 notitle with lines  dt solid  linecolor  rgb  "black "  ,   "-" binary record=(5,4) format="%double%double%double"   using 1:2:3 notitle with lines  dt solid  linecolor  rgb  "black "  ,   "-" binary record=(5,4) format="%double%double%double"   using 1:2:3 notitle with lines  dt solid  linecolor  rgb  "black "  ,   "-" binary record=(5,4) format="%double%double%double"   using 1:2:3 notitle with lines  dt solid  linecolor  rgb  "black "
```

As seen, the splot command contains four entries. I have tried sorting these entries from tallest to shortest before sending them to splot, but that has no change on `depthorder`.

My suspicion is that `depthorder` measures the quadrangles from their centers to the viewport of the plot and sorts by distance. There is an angle then that the tall quadrangles have centers closer than the shorter quadrangles, and consequently get drawn in a different order.

**Is this suspicion correct, or is there another issue at play here? Is there a solution to get `depthorder` measured 'correctly' in this case?**

For those who wish to recreate these graphs, here is a data file containing the isolines (each line is five (x,y,z) points, there are 4 lines for each cube (2 horizontal and 2 vertical), and four cubes):

```js
0 1 0 
0 1.9 0 
0 1.9 2 
0 1 2 
0 1 0 

1 1 0 
1 1.9 0 
1 1.9 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 0 

0 0 0 
0 0.9 0 
0 0.9 1 
0 0 1 
0 0 0 

1 0 0 
1 0.9 0 
1 0.9 0 
1 0 0 
1 0 0 


0.9 1 0 
0.9 1.9 0 
0.9 1.9 2 
0.9 1 2 
0.9 1 0 

1.9 1 0 
1.9 1.9 0 
1.9 1.9 1 
1.9 1 1 
1.9 1 0 

0.9 0 0 
0.9 0.9 0 
0.9 0.9 1 
0.9 0 1 
0.9 0 0 

1.9 0 0 
1.9 0.9 0 
1.9 0.9 0 
1.9 0 0 
1.9 0 0 


0 1 0 
0 1.9 0 
0.9 1.9 0 
0.9 1 0 
0 1 0 

1 1 0 
1 1.9 0 
1.9 1.9 0 
1.9 1 0 
1 1 0 

0 0 0 
0 0.9 0 
0.9 0.9 0 
0.9 0 0 
0 0 0 

1 0 0 
1 0.9 0 
1.9 0.9 0 
1.9 0 0 
1 0 0 


0 1 2 
0 1.9 2 
0.9 1.9 2 
0.9 1 2 
0 1 2 

1 1 1 
1 1.9 1 
1.9 1.9 1 
1.9 1 1 
1 1 1 

0 0 1 
0 0.9 1 
0.9 0.9 1 
0.9 0 1 
0 0 1 

1 0 0 
1 0.9 0 
1.9 0.9 0 
1.9 0 0 
1 0 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3D boxplots like that are now supported as a basic plot type in the development version of gnuplot.  See this online example:
    http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.3/3dboxes.html

The trick to make this work is that the box faces must be sorted by the z value at the base.   This is implemented in a new command variant

set pm3d depthorder base

I am not aware of any way to do this properly in earlier versions of gnuplot.

Answer (score 2):

I know that is an old question but, inspired by the [same gnuplotting entry](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-cubes/), I decided try something that really would works on `gnuplot 5.2.7`. It's actually a **proof of concept**!
I realized that, even using [`depthorder base`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55752935/11369382), the correct z-order is achieved just creating the cube faces in a certain sequence.
To illustrate, I used follows datafile to plot the *"cubes"*.

```
0.1 0.1 0.0
0.9 0.1 0.0
0.9 0.1 1.0
0.1 0.1 1.0
0.1 0.1 0.0

0.9 0.1 0.0
0.9 0.9 0.0
0.9 0.9 1.0
0.9 0.1 1.0
0.9 0.1 0.0

0.9 0.1 1.0
0.9 0.9 1.0
0.1 0.9 1.0
0.1 0.1 1.0
0.9 0.1 1.0

0.9 0.1 0.0
0.9 0.9 0.0
0.1 0.9 0.0
0.1 0.1 0.0
0.9 0.1 0.0
```

Using this code...

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo font "Ubuntu,10" size 1000,800
set output "3D_Graph.png"
set tics out nomirror
unset key
set xyplane at 0
unset colorbox

set arrow 1 from 0.55,0.40,0 to 1.45,0.4,0 nohead
set arrow 2 from 0.55,0.32,0 to 0.55,0.47,0 nohead
set arrow 3 from 1.45,0.32,0 to 1.45,0.47,0 nohead

set arrow 4 from 1.60,0.55,0 to 1.60,1.45,0 nohead
set arrow 5 from 1.55,0.55,0 to 1.65,0.55,0 nohead
set arrow  from 1.55,1.45,0 to 1.65,1.45,0 nohead

set style textbox opaque noborder fillcolor rgb "white"
set label 1 "0.9" at 0.95,0.2,0.0 boxed
set label 2 "0.9" at 1.70,1.0,0.0 boxed

set style line  1 lw 1.5 lc rgb "#fde725" 

# viridis colormap
set palette defined(\
    1 "#440154",\
    2 "#472c7a",\
    3 "#3b518b",\
    4 "#2c718e",\
    5 "#21908d",\
    6 "#27ad81",\
    7 "#5cc863",\
    8 "#aadc32",\
    9 "#fde725"\
)
# ================================================================================
set multiplot layout 2,2
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set view equal xyz
set view ,,1.5,1
set cbrange [0:1]
set grid ls -1 lc "gray"
set pm3d depthorder hidden3d
set pm3d implicit
unset hidden3d
set title "{/:Bold single cube}"

splot [0:2][0:2][0:1] "cube_points.dat" u ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):($3):(0) w l ls 1
unset for [i=1:6] arrow i
unset for [i=1:2] label i
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set grid xtics ytics ztics vertical layerdefault ls -1 lc "gray"
set view equal xy
set view ,,1.75,0.55
set xrange [0.25:6.6]
set yrange [0.25:4.0]
set zrange [0:100]
set ztics 20
set cbrange [0:*]

set object polygon from \
    graph 0, 0, 0 to \
    graph 1, 0, 0 to \
    graph 1, 1, 0 to \
    graph 0, 1, 0 to \
    graph 0, 0, 0 fc rgb "gray" fs transparent solid 0.50 noborder

set pm3d depthorder base border lw 0.5
set title "{/:Bold pm3d with depthorder base border lw 0.5}"

splot \
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):($3*15):(1) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+0.5):($2+1.5):($3*65):(1) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+0.5):($2+2.5):($3*85):(1) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+1.5):($2+0.5):($3*30):(2) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+1.5):($2+2.5):($3*75):(2) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+1.5):($2+1.5):($3*50):(2) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+2.5):($2+0.5):($3*30):(3) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+2.5):($2+1.5):($3*40):(3) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+2.5):($2+2.5):($3*60):(3) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+3.5):($2+0.5):($3*20):(4) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+3.5):($2+1.5):($3*50):(4) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+3.5):($2+2.5):($3*85):(4) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+4.5):($2+0.5):($3*25):(5) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+4.5):($2+1.5):($3*40):(5) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+4.5):($2+2.5):($3*50):(5) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+5.5):($2+0.5):($3*15):(6) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+5.5):($2+1.5):($3*30):(6) w pm3d,\
    "cube_points.dat" u ($1+5.5):($2+2.5):($3*40):(6) w pm3d

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set pm3d depthorder base lighting noborder
set title "{/:Bold pm3d with depthorder base lighting noborder}"
replot

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set pm3d depthorder base lighting border lw 0.5
set title "{/:Bold pm3d with depthorder base lighting border lw 0.5}"
replot
unset multiplot
```

... I was able to achieve this result:

[image: 3D boxbar using gnuplot]

It's works even under high-angled views:

[image: 3D horizontal rotation]

[image: 3D vertical rotation]

Of course that this code can't read `x y z`-type datafiles or create 3D-clustered bars charts, but is a beginning.

Comment: Amazing. I’ll try this out soon.