# Matplotlib 3D workaround for plot order

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I know that matplotlib 3D is not reliable for plotting multiple 3D objects (planes, lines, points) in the right order: please see [Matplotlib 3D plot zorder issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188561/matplotlib-3d-plot-zorder-issue) and [How to draw intersecting planes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824893/how-to-draw-intersecting-planes).
However these questions seem quite old, so the proposed solutions. Thus, I would like to know if there are some new developments, tools, workarounds or hard-coded solutions for the following specific simple scenario:

```
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as a3
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np    

fig = plt.figure()
ax = a3.Axes3D(fig)

# create an orizontal plane
corners = [[0,0,0],[0,5,0],[5,5,0],[5,0,0]]
tri = a3.art3d.Poly3DCollection([corners], alpha=1)
tri.set_color('w')
tri.set_edgecolor('k')
ax.add_collection3d(tri)

# plot a vector
ax.plot([2,2],[2,2],[0,4], c = 'r')

# plot some points
ax.scatter([1,3],[1,3],[1,3], c = 'r')

ax.set_xlim([0, 5.0])
ax.set_ylim([0, 5.0])
ax.set_zlim([0, 2.5]);

plt.show()
```

[image: In this image you can see the visualization issues: the vector it is not starting from the plane, as it should since his intiali point is (2,2,0)]

In this image you can see the visualization issues: the vector it is not starting from the plane, as it should since his intiali point is (2,2,0)

Comment: Your code produces the correct result for me. The red line starts at [2, 2, 0] as expected, and is not clipped. Matplotlib 2.1.1 and QT5Agg backend. Maybe your backend is at fault?

Comment: Works for me here too, red line starts at [2, 2, 0] as expected.  `matplotlib`2.2.3, `Qt5Agg` backend

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it does not solve the issue.
I tried also with both 'Qt5Agg' and 'WxAgg'

Comment: I'm sorry to read that - and the matplotlib version is also recent enough?

Comment: Yes, matplotlib version 3.0.0, python3.6

Comment: Bisects to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9094

Comment: Would you file a [bug report](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) for this?

Comment: Thank you so much. Here it is https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12620