# OpenGL: Saving depth map as 2d array

Tags: opengl

I am able to render depth maps of 3d models to the screen using openGL. I am trying to obtain a 2d array (or matrix) representation of the depth map, say as a grayscale image, so I can perform image processing operations on it, like masking and segmentation.

So far, my depth map simply prints depth values instead of the colors in the fragment shader. How can I save the resulting depth map display as a matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GLUT/OpenGL to render to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file)

Comment: I noticed that you have been asking quite a few questions in the past days. Most of them have been closed or down-voted. I highly encourage you to read [ask] and to do some more extensive research before posting questions. If you keep posting badly received questions, you might come close to a question ban.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use frame [buffer object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object). Attach texture to it as a depth attachment, and then use as normal texture. Have a look at [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ru/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) tutorial for example.